# How to locate element inside css footer

Tags: html, css, ruby, watir, page-object-gem

There are 2 text on page "ok" and "oops" one is under `<footer>` another under `class=> 'meta'`.
I want to verify footer text and I am using

```
span(:alert){div_element(:class => 'application').div_element(:class => 'txt').span_element(:class => 'app-text')}
```

but its verifying with meta "class" text "oops" as both have same div path.
How I can locate the span class "app-txt" inside footer specific?

```
<footer>
  <div class="application" style="opacity: 1;">
    <div class="txt" style="background-color: transparent;">
      <span class="app-txt" style="background-color: transparent;">ok</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>

<div class="meta">
  <div class="application" style="opacity: 1;">
    <div class="txt" style="background-color: transparent;">
      <span class="app-txt" style="background-color: transparent;">oops</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In CSS you would use `:first-child`: `footer :first-chilld .app-txt`. In your case it's even easier since only one of both is child of footer, so you can even leave out `:first-child` if your code example actually reflects your markup.

Comment: Are you trying to locate specific text in `CSS` or in `JAVASCRIPT` ?

Comment: js like span(:alert){div_element(:class => 'application').div_element(:class => 'txt').span_element(:class => 'app-text')} not in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate the <kbd>ok</kbd> use:

```
footer .app-txt
```

To locate the <kbd>oops</kbd> use:

```
.meta .app-txt
```

```css
footer .app-txt {color: red;}
.meta .app-txt {color: orange;}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="application" style="opacity: 1;">
    <div class="txt" style="background-color: transparent;">
      <span class="app-txt" style="background-color: transparent;">ok</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>

<div class="meta">
  <div class="application" style="opacity: 1;">
    <div class="txt" style="background-color: transparent;">
      <span class="app-txt" style="background-color: transparent;">oops</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you know that the two spans can be differentiated based on their ancestor element, ie the `<footer>` vs the `<div class="meta">`, you should include that in your locator.

**Solution 1 - Using Nested Locators**

The page object could be:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  # The span in the footer
  span(:in_footer) { footer_element.span_element(class: 'app-txt') }

  # The span in the meta div
  span(:in_meta) { div_element(class: 'meta').span_element(class: 'app-txt') }
end
```

As you can see, by including the differentiating ancestor element, ie the `footer_element` vs the `div_element(class: 'meta')`, you can get both texts:

```
p page.in_footer
#=> "ok"

p page.in_meta
#=> "oops"
```

**Solution 2 - Using CSS-Selectors**

Alternatively, depending on your comfort with CSS-selectors (or XPath), you could shorten the page object by using the CSS-selectors mentioned by @K.RajaSekharReddy or @PraveenKumar.

Using the CSS-selectors, the page object could be:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  span(:in_footer, :css => 'footer .app-txt')
  span(:in_meta, :css => '.meta .app-txt')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate the ok use:

```
footer >.application >.txt >span.app-txt {
   color: blue;
}
```

or

```
footer >span.app-txt {
   color: blue;
}
```

To locate the oops use:

```
.meta >.application >.txt >span.app-txt {
   color: orange;
}
```

or

```
.meta >span.app-txt {
   color: orange;
}
```

Comment: need locator like span(:alert){div_element(:class => 'application').div_element(:class => 'txt').span_element(:class => 'app-text')} not in css